# DataTable reload with Cordova app cause javascript crash

Tags: jquery, cordova, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and they works fine on all browser except when I embed my webapp in a native app with Cordova.

The problem is generated when I try to realod the table with different data. This occurs on an user button press. The code is the following:

```
var table = $('#table_container').DataTable();
if (table != null) {
   table.destroy(); //Crash here!
}
```

The crash occurs on destroy call, but I have replaced this function with any other valid call for DT and the result was the same. I initialized the DataTable earlier in this way:

```
var table = $('#table_container').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 100,
            "ordering": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "info": false,
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/i18n/Italian.json"
            },
            "initComplete": function () {
            var api = this.api();
             if(api.data().length <= 100){
                  $('#table_container_paginate').hide();
                  $('#table_container_filter').hide();
              }
            }
        });
```